# Including attributes for DXF blocks when exporting using gdal2gdal

Tags: qgis, gdal

When exporting points as block inserts using gdal2gdal/ convert format in QGIS I would like to be able to include block attributes based on attributes from my points to populate the blocks in the resulting DXF with information.
According to the [documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html) attributes can be dealt with when blocks are imported, so hopefully I can include some when exporting?

Inside a OSGEO4w shell I ran "set DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS=False" so blocks don't get exploded when I import a DXF.
The blocks are then imported with a "BlockAttributes" field as per the documentation. The format of the text is

> (2:Attribute1Name Attribute1Value,Attribute2Name Attribute2Value)

When I export a DXF with this "BlockAttributes" field and syntax I successfully get blocks defined in the header template inserted at the points  but the attributes are empty.

Documentation

> The entities layer will have several new fields:
>
> BlockName: The name of the referenced block.
>
> BlockScale: The X, Y, and Z scale factors.
>
> BlockAngle: The angle of the block in degrees.
>
> BlockOCSNormal (GDAL >= 2.3.0): The unit normal vector of the object
> coordinate system (OCS) of the INSERT entity.
>
> BlockOCSCoords (GDAL >= 2.3.0): The OCS coordinates of the insertion
> point.
>
> BlockAttributes (GDAL >= 2.3.0): The text content of attributes
> associated with this block. Each entry in this string list contains an
> attribute tag, followed by a space, followed by the text for that
> attribute (which may be empty).